# Whenever I run Protractor on Chrome, it opens up cmd with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, automation, protractor

I am running Protractor on Chrome. Everything was working fine until yesterday, since yesterday morning I am facing this issue.

Whenever I run it on Chrome, it opens up cmd with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`, and in the backend it opens Chrome, with "data" in the address bar [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmlF4.png). Nothing is happening from there on. I tried on different versions of Protractor, but none worked.

> node - 0.12.2 protractor - 2.1.0 selenium-webdriver: 2.45.1
>   chromedriver: 2.15
>
> node - 0.12.2 protracotor - 2.5.1 selenium-webdriver: 2.47.1
>   chromedriver: 2.19
>
> Chrome version - 46

Any help will be much appreciated.

My config file:

```
exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
specs: ['./app.js'],

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 2000000
}
};
```

My Spec:

```
'use strict';

describe('Tests', function() {

it('tests', function () {
    browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com");
});
});
```

Comment: I had the same issue today. So I uninstalled protractor and then installed again (the last version). It solved my problem.

Comment: i even tried that, initially i faced the issue on protractor - 2.1.0, so i uninstalled it and installed protractor - 2.5.1. But no luck

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code of protractor conf.js file and the way you get the url in your test specs? Thanks

Comment: are you calling `browser.get` in your onPrepare function?

Comment: @GirishSortur i update the question with config and spec file, i am just doing basic things. I am trying to open facebook page. Because i need to automate my application which runs inside FB.

Comment: @vrachlin, nope i am not using any onPrepare and onComplete, just baisc stuff. I update my question with config and spec. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updating the chromedriver manually resolved the issue. Downloaded the chromedriver 2.19 and replaced the old one in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. Updating to 2.5.1 solved the problem.